# Merge two csv files if Id columns match

Tags: bash, csv, command-line, text-processing

I have the following:

file1.csv

```
"Id","clientName1","clientName2"
```

file2.csv

```
"Id","Name1","Name2"
```

I want to read *file1* sequentially. For each record, I want to check if there is a matching `Id` in *file2*. There may be more than one match. For each match, I want to append `Name1, Name2` to the end of the record of *file1.csv*

So, possible result, if a record has more than one match in *file2*:

```
"Id","clientName1","clientName2","Name1","Name2","Name1","Name2"
```

Comment: Does it have to be bash? I would suggest more sophisticated language that allows you to open up a file as a database and then just do a `LEFT JOIN` on the two or something like that. Or even just use perl and slurp them both into hashes and do some quick manipulation in perl.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those things, however. I need to do this as quickly and easily as possible. Preferably on the command line or in a bash script, but I do know Java, PHP, etc. if it's easy to do it with those languages.

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify that file1 may have duplicate Ids, it actually has many more fields than shown also, but file2 is just those three fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex solution by using `join` and `GNU sed`

```
join -t , -a 1 file[12].csv | sed -r '$!N;/^(.*,)(.*)\n\1/!P;s//\n\1\2,/;D'
```

assume that both file1.csv and file2.csv are sorted by id and without header

**file1.csv**

```
1,c11,c12
2,c21,c22
3,c31,c32
```

**file2.csv**

```
1,n11,n12
1,n21,n22
1,n31,n32
2,n41,n42
```

gives a result of

```
1,c11,c12,n11,n12,n21,n22,n31,n32
2,c21,c22,n41,n42
3,c31,c32
```

---

**UPDATE**

In case where `file1.csv` might contain **duplicate ids** and **various field lengths**, I would suggest to perform a pre-process to make sure `file1.csv` is clean before joining with `file2.csv`

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1 FS $i}' file1.csv |\
    sort -u |\
    sed -r '$!N;/^(.*,)(.*)\n\1/!P;s//\n\1\2,/;D'
```

- the first awk process splits all data into (id, name) pairs
- `sort -u` sorts and uniques each pairs
- the last sed process merge all pairs with same ids into a single row

**input**

```
1,c11,c12
1,c12,c14,c13
1,c15,c12
2,c21,c22
```

**output**

```
1,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15
2,c21,c22
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about file[12].csv. I assume that's to be replaced with a file name. Can you tell me exactly which variables need to be replaced with what? Thx.

Comment: @Ken `file[12].csv` is basically equal to `file1.csv file2.csv`, it is just a cleaner way to represent similar files with same prefixes or suffixes

Comment: Thx but I was just simplifying it when I wrote that. They are two completely different file names. How would I code your line in that case? Or, I can try this anyway but changing the file names temporarily.

Comment: @Ken In that case, you just need to replace `file[12].csv` with say `clientname.csv name.csv` so eventually the full command would look like `join -t , -a 1 clientname.csv name.csv | sed -E '$!N;/^(.*,)(.*)\n\1/!P;s//\n\1\2,/;D'` those filenames are just placeholders

Comment: I just ran this and got error:  sed: invalid option -- E. I ran it on the command line. Do you know what needs to be adjusted?

Comment: @Ken what version of sed or operating system are you currently using?

Comment: If option `-E` is not available, you can try to replace the sed part with `sed '$!N;/^\(.*,\)\(.*\)\n\1/!P;s//\n\1\2,/;D'`

Comment: On Linux. I just typed in uname -r and got 
2.6.18-348.3.1.el5xen

Comment: @Ken Ok, it seems to be my fault, the option to enable extended regexp should be `-r` in `GNU sed` which I mistaken it for `-E` in `BSD sed`, (answer edited)

Comment: Would your code need to be different if file1 contains duplicate Id's? I ran it and that may be causing a problem.

Comment: @Ken By saying duplicate ids, do you mean that file1 might contain rows with same ids but with different client names for example `id1, cn1, cn2` and `id1, cn1, cn3` or do you mean by plainly duplicate rows?

Comment: File1 has many more fields than shown also, but file2 is just those three fields.

Comment: They're not duplicate rows but they may start with the same Id and names. As mentioned, I neglected to say that a file1 record actually contains many more fields. My bad if that matters. Sorry.

Comment: @Ken No problem :) just want to make sure that I understand the requirements. Answer updated for the case you mentioned.

Comment: To etopylight... My supervisor told me I could do it with an outer loop reading file1 and a nested loop reading file2, and comparing ids. I didn't realize that I could write logic like that in a bash script, just like programming. So it's done. However, I applaud you for trying to help and sticking with me through over a dozen comments. Thanks a million. Just tried to vote for your answer but it wouldn't record.

Comment: @Ken Nice to know that you have solved it by your own! By the way, it would be great if you can also post your bash solution too, it might be quite helpful to those who encounter the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid bash may not be the efficient solution but the following bash script would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A id_hash

while read line; do
    id=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 1)
    name=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 2-)
    if [ -z "${id_hash[$id]}" ]; then
        id_hash[$id]=$name
    else
        id_hash[$id]=${id_hash[$id]},$name
    fi
done < file1.csv

while read line; do
    id=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 1)
    name=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 2-)
    if [ -z "${id_hash[$id]}" ]; then
        id_hash[$id]=$name
    else
        id_hash[$id]=${id_hash[$id]},$name
    fi
done < file2.csv

for id in ${!id_hash[@]}; do
    echo $id,${id_hash[$id]}
done
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify that file1 may have duplicate Ids, it actually has many more fields than shown also, but file2 is just those three fields. Would this still work as shown?

Comment: In case file1 has duplicate IDs, add `if .. else .. fi` lines as shown in while loop for file2.  I've modified the code above accordingly.  Regarding #fields, it accepts arbitrary count of fields, which is represented in the `cut -f 2-` part.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the [OP's clarification in his/her comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943095/merge-two-csv-files-if-id-columns-match/46946194#comment80862774_46946194), here is the revised version of the **single** `awk` command which does merge in case there was duplicated IDs either in file1 or file2 or in both and if with different number of fields. [old version which it works for OP's current stated question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46946194/1)

```
awk -F',' '{one=$1;$1="";a[one]=a[one]$0} END{for (i in a) print i""a[i]}' OFS=, file[12]
```

For the inputs:

> **file1**
>
> ```
> "Id1","clientN1","clientN2"
> "Id2","Name3","Name4"
> "Id3","client00","client01","client02"
> "Id1","client1","client2","client3"
> ```
>
> **file2**
>
> ```
> "Id1","Name1","Name2"
> "Id1","Name3","Name4"
> "Id2","Name0","Name1"
> "Id2","Name00","Name11","Name22"
> ```

The output is merged *`file1`* and *`file2`* on same ***IDs***:

```
"Id1","clientN1","clientN2","client1","client2","client3","Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4"
"Id2","Name3","Name4","Name0","Name1","Name00","Name11","Name22"
"Id3","client00","client01","client02"
```

Comment: Yours is the first answer here that I'm capable of, so I'm going to try it first. It's exactly what I want if it works. I'll let you know.

Comment: Actually, I need a little clarification. Is the letter 'a' to be replaced with the file names? Can you tell me which variables are to be replaced with what? Thx.

Comment: Sorry, I also need to clarify that file1 may have duplicate Ids, it actually has many more fields than shown also, but file2 is just those three fields.

Comment: @Ken see my update, about `a` no it's an array named called `a`, files are `file[12]` which this expand to `file1 file2` (just shortened).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all but this has been completed. The code I wrote is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo
echo 'Merging files into one'

IFS=","
while read id lname fname dnaid status type program startdt enddt ref email dob age add1 add2 city postal phone1 phone2

do
var="$dnaid,$lname,$fname,$status,$type,$program,$startdt,$enddt,$ref,$email,$dob,$age,$add1,$add2,$city,$postal,$phone1,$phone2"

  while read id2 cwlname cwfname
  do
       if [ $id == $id2 ]
       then
           var="$var,$cwlname,$cwfname"
       fi

  done < file2.csv

  echo "$var" >> /root/scijoinedfile.csv

done < file1.csv

echo
echo "Merging completed"
```